# wordwrap issues with special characters in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, word-wrap, add-filter

In my WordPress blog, I inserted the following content in "Description" field in add new post form.

```
sss'ss''ss'''ss"ss""sss"""
```

I am applying the **filter hook(add_filter)** the the_content() function as below. Basically I want to display non spaced words if it exist more than 50 character means, I would like to give space after 50 characters. So I used *wordwrap* function to do that. But while use special characters in content I am getting wired output as mentioned below.

**function.php**

```
function filter_content($content) {
  global $post;  
     $original = wordwrap($content,50,' ',' ' ); 
  return $original;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_content' );
```

**Output :**

```
   sss’ss”ss”’ss”ss& #8221;"sss”"”
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have filtered `the_content() function` with the following function."? Are you appending function `the_content()` or are you applying a filter to **action HOOK** `the_content`? These are very different operations. It seems obvious the result you are getting is not generated by function wordwrap(), don't forget hook `the_content` is a popular way to modify the content and you don't know what other functions are already doing it or the way they do it.

Comment: Why do you think function [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.wordwrap.php) has anything to do with the strange characters at the output? Anyway, what is your question? There is no question in your "question", I only see statements.

Comment: Reading more in detail, you say **When i use the `the_content() function` in the single post page, it display following content with issue.**. I really don't get it. ¿Do you think the problem is with `the_content() function` when you use it, with the wordwrap in `the_content` hook, or with both? Impossible to guess, I will not waste my time trying to do it. Good luck.

Comment: I am applying a filter to action HOOK to  the_content function , Please look at question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

[wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.wordwrap.php) function is converting special charters(quotes, double quotes and etc..) into html entity and count as a string.50 character occurrence happen between & and # from  **”**. While it divide that we got output as **& #8221;**.

**Solution:**

Instead of php just try css solution **word-wrap** property. So apply *word-wrap:break-word;* style to your paragraph tag. break-word value will force to break the word. But there is no option to give numbers like 50 and all. It will wrap depends on container width.

```
p{
 word-wrap:break-word; 
}
```

Comment: I knew I shouldn't waste my time with this question. ¿Are you joking? Look at the tags ¿How can the question be related to CSS? Be serious please, it looks you invented the question for this surprising secret answer. Same could have been done in PHP with break and TRUE as parameters, by the way. Needless to say, that's a really bad solution, ¿who wants words broken at wordwrap? Only you.

Comment: @FarFromGenius: did you tried with <br> and true parameter or just guessing. That won't work. Yes no one wants to break the word. I know CSS solution is not a better. I am also tracking this question for better answer.! OP may change his mind, If someone post better than this.