# esc_html__ and special character in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, translation, html-escape

I use esc_html__ in my below code:

```
esc_html__( 'Best & Sea', 'textdomain' );
```

When I use the above code the special character & is not displayed.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, but your code displays the special character "&", so there is, somewhere else, something that is making trouble. When reading [`esc_html__()`WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) , it says *"Escaping for HTML blocks."*, so it displays any special character and just remove html blocks (tags).

Comment: as stated in the comment above the problem doesn't rely on the function call itself but what do you mean by saying _is not displayed_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordwrap issues with special characters in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619506/wordwrap-issues-with-special-characters-in-wordpress)

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
echo html_entity_decode(esc_html__('Best & Sea', 'textdomain'));
```